# wordpress https back to http

Tags: wordpress, http, https, wp-admin

I made a terrible mistake and i am not sure how to fix it. I have installed Force HTTPS (SSL Redirect & Fix Insecure Content) plugin on Wordpress and pressed activate by hoping it will be a plugin with steps how to make a secure webpage. Instead i have unworking website now. When you type in website name in front it makes https://website.com. Maybe you can tell me how can i revert it to http://website.com. As well i can't access wp-admin page. it gets the https:// in front...

Comment: go to file manager of your hosting, find your wordpress installation folder, go to wp-content -> plugins -> and find  Force HTTPS plugin folder( should be something like force_https ) and rename it. this way you will disable that plugin

Comment: I have deleted that folder and the problem remained the same...

Comment: it also can be browser cache issue now, another part you should to check: add your `.htaccess` file into your question. there may be some added rules. another part you can to check: go to phpmyadmin, find table `{your_wp_db_prefix}_options` and look at it's first 2 rows `siteurl` and `home` - check, if they are saved with `http`

Comment: Thank you. The problem was in the .htaccess file